# how to load data from big-query table to other database?(DB2)

Tags: google-bigquery

what are the ways to load data from big-query table to other database?
steps required to load data from big-query to other DB

Answer (score 2):

You have to do it in three steps:

1) Export data from BigQuery https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data

2) Prepare your data to be imported

3) Import in Db2